# UICollectionView select cell at indexPath while reloading

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, reloaddata

I have collection view to show photos from server.
downloading from server is slow and I want to show new downloaded photo in CollectionView.
I have this code for reload every time while photo is downloaded.

```
 for (int x = 0; x < thumbsLink.count; x++)
 {
     NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[thumbsLink objectAtIndex:x]]];
     UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
     {
         [thumbs addObject:image];
         [self.collectionView reloadData];
     });
 }
```

This works well, but I can't select cell for row at index path until downloading is complete.
How can I select cell before downloading is complete, to view already downloaded photo?

Comment: how could _Xcode_ select anything...?

Comment: Load the image asyncrhonously instead.

Answer (score 1):

Because you did work on the main thread instead of the async thread.

You should change your code to:

```
ClassOfSelf * __weak weakSelf = self;
for (int x = 0; x < thumbsLink.count; x++)
{
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[thumbsLink objectAtIndex:x]]];
         UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
         [thumbs addObject:image];
         [[weakSelf collectionView] reloadData];
     });
}
```

You also need to use `weak` reference for self for avoid strong reference cycles.

You can also do this in a concurrent enumeration block:

```
ClassOfSelf * __weak weakSelf = self;
[thumbsLink enumerateObjectsWithOptions: NSEnumerationConcurrent usingBlock: ^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
   NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:obj]];
   UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
   [thumbs addObject:image];
   [[weakSelf collectionView] reloadData];
}];
```

From Apple's documentation:

> If the code in the enumeration block is processor-intensive—and safe for concurrent execution—you can use the NSEnumerationConcurrent option:
>
> This flag indicates that the enumeration block invocations may be distributed across multiple threads, offering a potential performance increase if the block code is particularly processor intensive. Note that the enumeration order is undefined when using this option.

Comment: thanks for answer. loading images is now faster, but how can i simultaneously load images, reload and select downloaded images, because in some folders i have more then 500 pictures. thanks